# How can I export default from import?

Tags: node.js, typescript, hapi.js

Using the following to apply routes to [hapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/hapi).

How can I refactor `export * from './foo';` to replace `*` by the default export of each route?

## routes/index.ts

```js
'use strict';

export * from './foo'; // This is the line I’m trying to refactor
```

## routes/foo.ts

```js
'use strict';

import hapi from '@hapi/hapi';

const foo = [
  {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v1/clients/me',
    config: {
      ...
    },
    handler: async (request:hapi.Request, h:hapi.ResponseToolkit): Promise<hapi.ResponseObject> => {
      ...
    }
  },
];

export default foo;
```

**This works, but looking for a one-liner.**

```js
'use strict';

import foo from './foo';
export const _foo = foo;
```

Comment: `export { default as _foo} from './foo'`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Is there a way to skip `as _foo`? Btw, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean export default from './foo' as default? Yes `export {default} from './foo'`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That appears to only work for one route... Adding `export {default} from './bar'` throws an error. Btw, feel free to add your answer and I will upvote. So far, it’s the best.

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
'use strict';

import hapi from '@hapi/hapi';

export default const foo = [
  {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v1/clients/me',
    config: {
      ...
    },
    handler: async (request:hapi.Request, h:hapi.ResponseToolkit): Promise<hapi.ResponseObject> => {
      ...
    }
  },
];
```

`

Comment: Did you try to run your code? I believe `export default const foo = ...` will throw an error. Also, you can use ``` syntax to create code blocks.